# How to make turtle.onscreeenclick() return true or false answers

Tags: turtle-graphics

I was wondering how can I make the function:

```
turtle.onscreenclick()
```

return me a `True` or `False` answer.

For example, if I click on the turtle window I want it to return `True`

Comment: you could assign `turtle.onscreenclick` to a variable, then use an `if` statement to detect if it is pressed.